# Cannot read property 'focus' of null error for React-Native-Phone-Input library focus function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-phone-input library for my project. When I used their focus function it worked for the first time, but after that when I type a phone number it gives me a Cannot read property 'focus' of null error.

My code:

```js
< PhoneInput
ref = { (ref) => {ref.focus()}}
initialCountry = 'ca'
flagStyle = {
  {
    width: 50,
    height: 30,
    borderWidth: 0,
    marginLeft: "29%"
  }
}
textStyle = {
  {
    fontSize: 30,
    height: 35
  }
}
autoFormat = {
  true
}
onChangePhoneNumber = {
  (number) => this.handleChange(number)
}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION:

Please do it like this:

`< PhoneInput  ref={(ref) => { this.phone = ref; }}`

assigning the ref to this.phone.

Now in `ComponentDidMount`  write `this.phone.focus()`.

### REASON:

Refs are not guaranteed to be set when component is Rendering, So you have to use refs in `componentDidMount`. Whenever you writes something in the inputText, The state changes and it re-renders the component due to which ref is null at that time! So use ref in componentDidMount so it will be called after complete rendering so it will work.

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
componentDidMount=()=>{
    this.phone.focus()
}


<PhoneInput
ref={(ref) => { this.phone = ref; }}
initialCountry = 'ca'
flagStyle = {
  {
    width: 50,
    height: 30,
    borderWidth: 0,
    marginLeft: "29%"
  }
}
textStyle = {
  {
    fontSize: 30,
    height: 35
  }
}
autoFormat = {
  true
}
onChangePhoneNumber = {
  (number) => this.handleChange(number)
}
/>
```

Comment: Very helpful!  Thank you!

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you!, 
Welcome on StackOverflow,
If i have properly answered your question you can mark it as an answer, read more here=> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers